# How to use AngularJS ng-include?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS to separate my jquery mobile HTML. But it seems `ng-include` can't include external HTML as the parent content, parent CSS and js are not applied to it. Below is an example. Would you like to let me know how to fix it?

Below is the example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/I91t9mjGJ58ZS4H2bymL?p=preview

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. As such, there is a reason you are asked to not post links without code! If you can add a small example to the question itself, it will both get more attention and be of value to future readers, and those who cant access plunker.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious you cannot directly access external file from other site due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) policy.

If you do want to get the template from other site with different domain name, make sure that domain provides the API for you to `$http.get` the html template string, and then you can inject it into your Angular controller, where your view may access from.

The basic process may be as follow:

1. Check the API for the third party domain, where you can get the template string.
2. Use `$http.get` (or `$resource`, depends on your choice) to get the template.
3. Wrap the `$http` service and your parsing login into a new Angular service. (e.g. `angular.module('yourApp', []).factory();`
4. Inject this service into the Angular controller which you bind in your directives.
5. In your view file, use `ng-include` in that controller to access the template.